# How to send the content of SSL-related files to the API call | PHP | cUrl

Tags: php, json, file, ssl, file-get-contents

I have two files for SSL `ssl_crt` and `ssl_key`. I want to read the content of these files and send it to the APIs as a JSON field. But the `file_get_contents` actually convert the single slash to double so the API return the following error.

> The private key format is invalid.
>
> The certificate format is invalid.

I am actually using run cloud service where I want to send the content of these files to one of their API

> https://runcloud.io/docs/api/web-application#ssl-basic-install-ssl

As you can see in the above URL, they need the content in the proper format.

So I tried the following.

```
$curl = curl_init();

$ssl_crt = file_get_contents(selectServer()->ssl_crt_path);
$ssl_key = file_get_contents(selectServer()->ssl_key_path);

$data = [
    'provider' => 'custom',
    'enableHttp' => true,
    'enableHsts' => false,
    'certificate' => $ssl_crt,
    'privateKey' => $ssl_key,
];

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://manage.runcloud.io/api/v2/servers/{id}/webapps/{webapp_id}/ssl',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic {token}'
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

If I manually write the content of the certificate(or key) to the data array then it works fine. i.e

```
$data = [
    // ...
    'certificate' => '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nblah\nblah==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----,
    'privateKey' => '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nblah\nblah==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----,
];
```

The actual issue with the format. the "\n" becomes "\n" and the main content of the certificate or key can have "\n".

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: ```But the file_get_contents actually convert the single slash to double``` - no, they don't. what do you get from ```var_dump(bin2hex(file_get_contents(selectServer()->ssl_key_path)));``` ?

Comment: I mean they escape the slash.

Comment: No, file_get_contents does *not* escape slashes. the problem is not with file_get_contents, the problem is elsewhere. run `echo(bin2hex(file_get_contents(selectServer()->ssl_key_path)));` then paste the hex into a hex editor and check, does the hex decode to double-slashes?

Comment: `var_dump(bin2hex(file_get_contents(selectServer()->ssl_key_path)));` give `string(11388) a-long-hexa-string ` kind of thing.

Comment: I copy the content of the Hexa string to text and it returns the same content that I have in my file.

Comment: The issue can also with the json_encode() function but I am already using `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag.

Comment: hmm, var_export() should reveal the difference, but.. blah, are you on facebook or Discord? can you contact me?  ( Discord: takeoded#1532 / facebook: https://www.facebook.com/hanshenrik.bergan ), catch me when i'm bored and i might be able to help

Answer (score 0):

the post-mortem here is that the on-disk file was corrupted, the on-disk file had all newlines converted to literal-slash-followed-by-n, which PHP's double-quote operator was fixing, thus it worked when you hardcoded the file (with php's double-quote operator. it would not have worked with php's single-quote operator), and didn't work when you got it from file_get_contents() - code used to fix the on-disk file was

```php
<?php
$real_crt=file_get_contents("ssl_crt");
$fixed_crt = strtr($real_crt,array(
    "\\n"=>"\n",
    "\\r"=>"\r",
));
file_put_contents("ssl_crt_fixed",$fixed_crt);
```

i only figured this out after you sent me the ssl_cert file on facebook messenger, though, and i'm pretty sure the ssl_cert file was required to solve this mystery, so i have voted to close this question as `requires the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.` ie, it needs the ssl_cert file to be any kind of reproducible

Comment: Really happy with the assistance of Hans Henrik. I have a kind of corrupted file. So it will be better if you also put the code to fix the file content. Happy coding.

Comment: I think you are right to say about `close the question` as there is no problem with json_encode or file_get_contents.